# CSS image hover does not work

Tags: html, css

i have another one problem.please guide me..

```
#footer-menu  .homeButton a {
background-image: url('homebutton.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:70px;
padding:5px 8px 50px 15px;
border:none;
width:70px;
}
```

in this code when I change the position as top left,it display only white image.how to change the position.

```
#footer_menu .homeButton:hover a{
background:none;
}
#footer_menu .homeButton a:hover{
background:url("homebutton2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
 }
```

And in this above code when I hover over the image,it will not shown the homebutton2 image.what i do?please help me.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yes first create a fiddle if you can

Answer (score 1):

this rule hides the anchor.
`#footer_menu .homeButton:hover a{
background:none;
}`

Comment: dear friend,i delete the hiding function,but till now it wont work

Comment: You have some errors in your code,
note you are calling sometimes #footer_menu and sometimes #footer-menu
with a typo

Comment: use this fiddle as a base http://jsfiddle.net/6NjQw/13/   (assuming this is what you were trying to do, change the background of the button, and the background of the underlying element)